# Can the "award" property be used for ISO certification of the company?

Tags: schema.org

As my organization is ISO-certified and it is mentioned in the website too, can I use the [`award` property](http://schema.org/award) to provide this certification information?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can use ISO certified as schema award markup in person, organization, Product or creativework.

It's a text field and you are allowed to write eg: "ISO 2015 Certified Company"

Here's an example for organization mark up validated using structured data testing tool. [ Details provided is not valid]

> {   "@context":
>   "http://schema.org",   "@type": "Organization",   "name": "TEST
>   Company.",   "url": "https://test.com",   "legalName": "TEST
>   Incorporated",   "leiCode": "12345678111Y",   "naics": "11111",
>   "duns": "123333333",   "taxID": "11-111111",   "vatID": "111111111",
>   "email": "info@test.com",   "description": "Test is a company based in
>   Utah US that codes and sells applications.",   "alternateName": [
>       "Test",
>       "Testing"   ],   "mainEntityOfPage": "https://techcrunch.com/news/test",   "sameAs":
>   "https://wikipedia.org/organization/test",   "logo":
>   "https://test.com/imagestest.jpg",   "image": [
>       "https://test.com/images/test1.jpg",
>       "https://test.com/images/test2.jpg",
>       "https://test.com/images/test3.jpg"   ],   "alumni": "TEST",   "award": "ISO 2015 Certified Company",   "brand": [
>       "XooTee",
>       "XooShoes",
>       "XooPremium"   ],   "address": {
>         "@type": "PostalAddress",
>         "addressLocality": "qwert", 
>         "postalCode": "123432",
>         "streetAddress": "qwertyu"   },   "contactPoint": {
>       "contactType": "Customer Service",
>       "email": "tets@test.com",
>       "telephone": "+1234567890",
>       "productSupported": "qwertyu",
>       "hoursAvailable": [
>         "Mo-Fri 08:00-20:00", 
>         "Sa-Su 10:00-18:00" 
>       ],
>       "url": "https://test.com/press"   },   "founder": "Jim Test",   "foundingDate": "1904-08-10",   "numberOfEmployees": "100",   "seeks":
>   "Fame" }